# Pig script running into jave heap space error 2997

Tags: apache-pig, heap-memory

Here is the pig stack trace. I am running my code over daily data individually, but it will fail some days. Others are done within 5 min. I have about 10 group all parallel 1 at the end to do some counts. Is this the reason of error?

### Backend error message

Error: Java heap space

### Pig Stack Trace

```
ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: Java heap space

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: Java heap space
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.getStats(MapReduceLauncher.java:819)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:452)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:282)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1431)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeCompiledLogicalPlan(PigServer.java:1416)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.execute(PigServer.java:1405)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:456)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.executeBatch(PigServer.java:439)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:171)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:234)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:495)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: Java heap space
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.Launcher.getErrorMessages(Launcher.java:215)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.getStats(MapReduceLauncher.java:803)
    ... 19 more
```

================================================================================

### Pig Stack Trace

```
ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message

org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2244: Job failed, hadoop does not return any error message
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.executeBatch(GruntParser.java:179)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:234)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:81)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:495)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:170)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```